# Suppress "Chart Area" tooltip in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I don't mind the "Chart Area" tooltip showing when I hover my mouse over an actual chart, but the tooltip is displaying on sheets where there are no charts. It seems like Excel is showing tooltips for hidden sheets even when I am on a sheet with no charts.

How can I disable this in Excel or VBA? I have tried the following:

Excel: File -> Options -> Advanced -> Untick "Show chart element names on hover"
VBA: Application.ShowToolTips = False

I also don't see any property of the chart that I could change that would suppress tooltips.

Comment: Can't reproduce - can you provide steps (and your Excel version) ?

Comment: There are no steps. This workbook has a lot of worksheets in it, some with charts and some without. Every page - even those without charts - shows the "Chart Area" tooltip when I navigate to the sheet. Once I select a cell, the tooltip goes away. If I move the mouse off the Excel application and back on, then the tooltip returns.

Comment: Also Office 2019.

Comment: OK I see it too.  Couldn't see a fix.  Similar (2010!)  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2010-pop-up-label-appearing/277a0652-3f7b-4084-b7d6-9f6ac920a9e8

Comment: Thanks for trying, Tim. I saw quite a few people complaining about this problem going back to Office 2010 and no fix then or now.

Comment: This has been happening to me for years. It really bothers me, but I've reported it to Microsoft to no avail. If it happens again, send a frown, and include the screenshot so they see the orphan popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed Office and the problem disappeared.

I tried reproducing the problem in other workbooks, but I only ever got the problem in a particular workbook, and the problem persisted in that workbook even if I saved it with a new name. I re-installed Office a few days ago and have not experienced the problem since.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 365 (version 2005) I have found a solution (for charts and most other annoying recurring tooltips I came across at least):
Go to Options -> Advanced -> Chart, untick 'Show chart element names on hover'

I couldn't find this anywhere else online, so I thought I'd share, even though this post is somewhat old now.

Might be different or not available for older Excel versions, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

You can turn of chart screen tips in the following way (with Excel 2019)
File -> Options -> Advanced -> Chart
then uncheck "Show chart element names on hover" and "Show data point values on hover"[image: Screen Shot]